# Calculate the distance between points with large xy values

Tags: java, android, math, geometry, distance

I'm trying to compare the distance between Point 1 and Point 2 with the distance between Point 1 and Point 3. And I'm trying to find the smaller one. The only problem is that the xy values of all three points are rather large and using the distance formula will likely cause an overflow. Is there another way to find the distances?

Comment: did u write a point class with x,y as integer fields?

Comment: Double.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157E308, are your distances really that big?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy No, I'm using the Point class provided to me (android.graphics.Point)

Comment: please tag with android...removing my answer..

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy Android does, in fact, support Big Integer so your answer was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale the values by a constant, calculate the distance, then "unscale" the values.  For example, divide your values by 10^6, or 10^9, or whatever it takes, then calculate the scaled distance and then convert back using your scale constant.

Comment: If I scale the values down, then can't I compare the two scaled distances without needing to "scale back up"?

Comment: Yes, if you just need to know the relative distances then you don't have to scale back up.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.hypot()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) may be useful in this context, as "the final result is without medium underflow or overflow."

Comment: I suspect the word _medium_ may be taken to mean _intermediate_.

Comment: 'hypot' a) works with doubles b) is slow, for it counts sqrt, that is useless for comparison of distances.

Comment: @Gangnus: Good points; I typically use `double` in the model and convert to `int` in the view; an example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2127971/230513).

Answer (score 1):

It is the fastest solution:

```
double dx12=x1-x2;
double dy12=y1-y2; 
double dx13=x1-x3; 
double dy13=y1-y3; 
double r12sq=dx12*dx12+dy12*dy12;
double r13sq=dx13*dx13+dy13*dy13;
int minR= r12sq>r13sq ? Math.sqrt(r13sq) : Math.sqrt(r12sq);
```

you need to take only one sqrt - that one for the shortest distance.

Normalization by some fixed constant is senseless for double.

If you use integers instead of doubles, the normalization and centering of coordinates by some fixed constant could be useful for some distances and bad for others. For example, if you are dividing by 1000, it is good for coordinates that have differences about some billions, but for differences about some hundreds its effect will be killing. So, you can evaluate the useful coefficient of normalization only after you have the medium dx and dy.  Let us you need 4 digits for work

```
int dx12=x1-x2;
int dy12=y1-y2; 
int dx13=x1-x3; 
int dy13=y1-y3; 
int d=(abs(dx12) +abs(dx13) + abs(dy12) + abs(dy13));

int coeff = d/10000;
if(coeff<1) coeff=1;

int dx12=dx12/coeff;
int dy12=dy12/coeff; 
int dx13=dx13/coeff; 
int dy13=dy13/coeff;

int r12sq=dx12*dx12+dy12*dy12;
int r13sq=dx13*dx13+dy13*dy13;
int minR= r12sq>r13sq ? Math.sqrt(r13sq) : Math.sqrt(r12sq);
```

Here you can multiply these int variables without overflow.

Comment: Please explain why scaling the values is "dangerous".